# OS X keyboard numeric key pad clearing numbers and beeping

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am using a regular Dell keyboard, it has the "clear" key, not sure if that is important.

Every time I enter in numbers using the numeric key pad into the calculator it clears the current number and enters in a new one as opposed to letting me enter a continuous number like 123. Also when I enter numbers into the browser address bar using the numeric key pad it does the same and it beeps on every number entered.

Not sure what to do, googled the problem but nothing has worked so far.

I am running MAC OS Mojave

Comment: Is it a keyboard for a regular computer? (i.e. not a POS terminal, etc)

Comment: Grab [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) from the app store & make sure what the keyboard actually generates when a key is pressed/released.

Comment: It's a regular Dell keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to me and am putting the answer out there for others who encounter the same. I assume the original question was handled in the last 3 years.

The issue comes from having NumLock on.

Try turning NumLock off on your keyboard/number pad.

Hope this helps.